# HP ALM: Extract defects of a target release with a predefined filter

Tags: filter, hp-quality-center, defects

I try to extract all the defects linked to a target release with a predefined filter
in order to export the data into excel with VBA.

Can anyone help me? Currently, I don´t have an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure the field related to the release is filled for all defects.
Then,

1. Go to the Defects Module
2. in the Defects Grid, there is a little button with a green table on it on top of the grid, that's the "Select Column" button.
3. Press the "Select Column" button
4. Use the arrows to move the release field from the list of hidden fields to the list of the fields shown on the grid (move it from the LHS list to the RHS list using the arrow)
5. Now the release will appear at the defects grid top.
6. Under the field name, there is a white edit box that is used for the grid filtration using that field and it's the same for all the other fields.
7. Click on that field, a list will be displayed and you can choose the target release from it.
8. The defects grid will be filtered by the release you have selected.
9. Now you can Press Shift+A to select the entire grid, then Right Click on one of the defects and choose Export then All.
10. Pop up will be displayed for you to type the file name and save. 
    your defects grid will be exported to the Excel sheet, and all the columns exported to that sheet are only the columns appearing on the QC Defects Grid.